# Enable decimal qty cause problem when updating cart qty magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, qty

I need to the allow decimal qty so I set it to yes but qty can be integer also. So when I updated my qty to integer number it show me warning : **please enter a valid value**. Why do I have this behaviour and how to disable this. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled the functionality in advanced inventory to allow decimals? to do this go to your admin

Catalog -> Product -> Advanced Inventory ->  Qty Uses Decimals -> Yes

remember to save the product before updating its inventory as it will still be validating for an integer